# how can i manage this error? Mismatched input 'pair' expecting ')'

Tags: binance, tradingview-api

how can i manage this error? Mismatched input 'pair' expecting ')'.

**I cannot remove all the brackets otherwise the message is not read by the binance api**

```
strategy.entry ("RSILong", strategy.long , alert_message=" {"pair":"BTCUSDT","isBuy":true,"isSell":false,"isMarket":true,"isLimit":false,"isClose":false,"unitsPercent":"100","unitsType":"percentBalance","useTrailingStopLoss":false,"stopLossToBreakEven":false,"marginType":"ISOLATED","targets":[],"leverage":"125","closeCurrentPosition":true,"preventPyramiding":false,"reduceOnly":false,"limitPriceType":"fixedPrice","useDca":false,"dcaPercent":5,"token":"xxxxxxxx","exchange":"Binance-Futures","apiKey":"bin future"}" )
```

Answer (score 0):

The quotes within the JSON string (`{"pair":"BTCUSDT", ...`) cause the mismatch.

---

**Solution**: Wrap the `alert_message` value in single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"`.

```
strategy.entry ("RSILong", strategy.long , alert_message='<your_json_string>' )
```